# Core data replacing to-many set

Tags: ios, core-data

Quick question, if I want to replace a to-many relationship completely. Do I need to delete all the previous objects, or is that done automatically

```
newVariable.hasRel = [NSSet setWithSet:newSet];
```

Where the variable has had some objects in that set, will just replacing it with the new set get rid of the old entities ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: Assigning a new set of related objects does not delete the previously related objects. You have to do that manually.

Comment: @user1028028: Theoretically, you could override the dynamically generated setter method for the relationship property to do that "behind the scenes". - Or you write a custom method `replaceAndDelete` that does both.

Comment: but if I delete the entity that has thous objects and the relationship is set to Cascade then they will be deleted , right?